# Error while importing paramiko in python script

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm trying to build a python script which has the line "import paramiko" and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.1-py3.4.egg/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.1-py3.4.egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.1-py3.4.egg/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py", line 89, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import FortunaGenerator
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 36, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "/home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 50, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import _AES
ImportError: /home/FBML7HR/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: rpl_malloc
```

I've installed pycrypto and paramiko modules. Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: somebody had a similar issue with pycrypto and fixed by setting an env and doing a re-install. Check out https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/138

Comment: I will post the link as an answer so you can mark it as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somebody had a similar issue with pycrypto and fixed by setting an env and doing a re-install. Check out http://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/138